# How to transform this in a function taking my load as parameters and add a play button to move the graph?

Tags: matlab

It's a MATLAB code where I want to pass the load as parameter

```
function Test
    a=axes('Position',[0.05,0.75,0.9,0.2])
    load('FilteredSignal.mat');//want to pass this as parameter

    fs = 1000;              // Sampling rate
    N = length (FilteredSignal(1,:));       // Signal length
    t = [0:N-1]/fs;         
    plot(t, FilteredSignal,'r');
    yL = get(a,'YLim');
    hold on
    for x=1:70
    plot([x x],yL,'k:');
    end
    // dr is the width of the axis 'window'
    dr=10;
    // This avoids flickering when updating the axis
    set(a,'xlim',[0 dr]);
    // Generate constants for use in uicontrol initialization
    pos=get(a,'position');
    Newpos=[pos(1) pos(2) pos(3) 0.02];
    xmax=max(t);
    S=['set(gca,''xlim'',get(gcbo,''value'')+[0 ' num2str(dr) '])'];
    // This will create a slider which is just underneath the axis
    // but still leaves room for the axis labels above the slider
    h=uicontrol('style','slider',...
        'units','normalized','position',Newpos,...
        'callback',S,'min',0,'max',xmax-dr);


end
```

Answer (score 1):

Alter your first line to:

```
function [] = Test(filename)
```

and change the `load` line to:

```
load(filename)
```

This way it's an input parameter. Make sure to pass the file name as a string though, i.e. `filename = 'FilteredSignal.mat';`

Comment: ok,thanks but how will i do to plot it? coz i've tried but nothing was plot.

Comment: First up: SO pretends to be a proper knowledge database, so you might want to work on your textsp34k.  Second: I have no experience whatsoever with UI control, so I cannot help you with that.